# Facebook Pixel and FireFox infinite loading

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have two questions related to the newer version of Facebook Pixel - any help is appreciated:

1. In FireFox when a page initially loads, it sends multiple requests to Facebook which never resolve. This prevents the site's favicon from showing because you just see the spinner icon. All other browsers seem to have no problem obtaining this pixel resource from Facebook.
2. I removed the Facebook Pixel script block from the site, cleared cookies, refreshed etc, and yet I still see these GET requests that never resolve (no response). Any idea why the site is still requesting these Facebook resources when there's no reference to the script block?

Here's the script I'm using (with a sample id)

```
  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
        !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
            if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
            }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
            n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
            t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
        }(window,
        document, 'script', '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

        fbq('init', '12345678908');
        fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=12345678908&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounters a similar situation, we also have Google Tag Manager and the old version of the Facebook Pixel script was being injected into the site via GTM.